# When trying to click the upload button after uploading the file into the input field internal validation displays as File is Required in Cypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cypress, cypress-file-upload

Below is the code i'm using to upload the file into the system from the test runner.

```
 it.only('Check the item upload file validations', () => {
    cy.get('[icon="fa fa-cloud-upload"]').click()
    cy.get('[id="itemListController"]',{force:true}).attachFile('itemfile.xlsx')
    cy.get('.p-float-label > [type="submit"]').click()
    // cy.pause()  
})
```

When the cypress the code executes , it displays a system internal validation as if the file is not being attached to the web page to be uploaded even though the file name is clearly being displayed in the input field.

[image]

Below is the element im trying to upload the file in to before clicking the submit button

```
<input _ngcontent-wul-c516="" id="itemListController" formcontrolname="itemListController" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" type="file" hidden="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice in the HTML `id="fileText"` and `formcontrolname="itemListController"` but you have selector `[id="itemListController"]`, so maybe

```js
cy.get('[formcontrolname="itemListController"]').attachFile('itemfile.xlsx')

//or

cy.get('[id="fileText"]').attachFile('itemfile.xlsx')
```

There's no `force` option on `cy.get()` so you can take that out.

But it's not the whole story, you do end up with the file name in the input.

I notice `ng-untouched` is present which may be causing the validation problem. Try adding a blur

> @property {boolean} $untouched True if control has not lost focus yet.

```js
cy.get('[id="fileText"]').attachFile('itemfile.xlsx').blur()
```

Comment: You are correct ! I've mistakenly inserted another element. i have edited the original question with the correct element included.

also , i've tried the solution you mentioned which displayed as below.

"cy.blur() can only be called when there is a currently focused element."

Comment: Try `.attachFile('itemfile.xlsx').focus().blur()` just to completely explore that avenue.

Comment: Other than that, it's a validation error message (see `ng-invalid` class) - do you have access to the source to see what validation is applied to the field.

Comment: <a href="https://imgur.com/wrTT0t5"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/wrTT0t5.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Display as above

Comment: Also try forcing the click with `cy.get('.p-float-label > [type="submit"]').click({force:true})`. That may allow you to by-pass the validation error if you cannot clear it another way.

Comment: cy.blur() can only be called when there is a currently focused element. still being displayed.

Comment: See above `.focus().blur()`.

Comment: ```
this.uploadItemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  itemListController: ['', Validators.required],
  file: []
}); 

``` </br> this is the source

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform the file upload by using the below cypress method.

[Cypress Documentation on .selectFile() Method](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile)

```
 it.only('Check the item upload file validations', () => {
    cy.get('[icon="fa fa-cloud-upload"]').click()
    cy.get('[id="itemListController"]').selectFile("cypress/fixtures/itemfile.xlsx",{force: true})
    cy.get('.p-float-label > [type="submit"]').click()
})
```